# Tabular Misalignment

Tags: tables

How can I fix column 4 so that it's aligned the same as the other columns? Note that if the columns only consisted of the numerals (row 2), that column 4 would *still* be misaligned.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{memoir}

\newcommand{\instruction}[1]{\begin{scriptsize} \textsf{#1} \end{scriptsize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}}

one & two & three & four \\
1111 & 2222 & 3333 & 4444

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the blank line after `4444`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a blank line after the last cell `4444`. I also made a newcolumntype `M` defined as `\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}}` to simplify the header.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{memoir}

\newcommand{\instruction}[1]{\begin{scriptsize} \textsf{#1} \end{scriptsize}}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}}

\begin{tabular}{M *3{|M}}
  one  & two   & three  & four \\
  1111 & 2222  & 3333   & 4444
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]